# django background JSON codeerror

Tags: python, django, postman

this  is  my  view

```
class BooksAPIVIew(View):
    def get(self,request):
        books = BookInfo.objects.all()
        books_list = []
        for  book  in  books:
            book_dict = {
                "btitle":book.btitle,
                "bpub_date": book.bpub_date,
                "bread":book.bread,
                "bcomment":book.bcomment,
            }
            books_list.append(book_dict)
        return JsonResponse(books_list,safe=False)
    def post(self,request):
        data_dict = json.loads(request.body.decode())
        book =BookInfo.objects.create(**data_dict)

        book_dict = {
            "btitle": book.btitle,
            "bpub_date": book.bpub_date,
            "bread": book.bread,
            "bcomment": book.bcomment
        }
        return    JsonResponse(book_dict,status=201)
```

this  is  my   model

```
class BookInfo(models.Model):
    btitle = models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name="名称")
    bpub_date=models.DateField(verbose_name="发布日期")
    bread = models.IntegerField(default=0,verbose_name="阅读量")
    bcomment = models.IntegerField(default=0,verbose_name="评论量")
    is_delete = models.BooleanField(default=False,verbose_name="逻辑删除")

    class  Meta:
        db_table = "tb_books"  
        verbose_name = "图书"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
```

this  is  url

```
 

from  django.conf.urls  import  url
from  Booktest import  views
from  django.urls import path

urlpatterns=[
      path("books/",views.BooksAPIVIew.as_view()),
      path('books/<int:book_id>/', views.BookInfoDetailView.as_view())

]
```

there is no problem with this view get request   ,  but when I use postman to http://127.0.0.1 : 8000 / books /    send a post request, the server returns 500 status code, and the error message is shown in the following screenshot,my version of Python is  3.63！

[image]

Comment: What happens if you `print(JsonResponse(books_list,safe=False).content)`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not send a body in your POST request with Postman. So the body received by Django is empty, which typically procudes these errors :

```py
>>> import json
>>> json.loads("")
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

So check that you actually send a body with Postman.